# Incoming webhook have a risk?

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

The webhooks endpoint is visible by the group member. If the group member share the webhooks endpoint to other. If someone with malicious intent got that URL, he/she could send Actionable Message with form and send the contents of that form to endpoint that is beyond your control.

- Is that will caused outsider to send many junk message to Teams?
- How can I solve this problem?
- Can I set the webhooks endpoint only visible by the group admin?

Answer (score 2):

By definition webhooks are un-authenticated. Anyone who has the URL can send to it...just like an email message.

If the webhook is compromised, delete it. It can no longer be used once it's deleted.